# Can add fields to Slightly Modified Options Framework 1.5.1

Tags: wordpress

I use Slightly Modified Options Framework 1.5.1 to add theme option page in my theme.

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Input Text",
        "desc"      => "A text input field.",
        "id"        => "counter",
        "std"       => "Default Value",
        "type"      => "text"
);
```

When i try to add a field, it shows only the label. The filed and the description is not exists. Also something happens with the layout. But when I change the version to the older, everything works.

Comment: are you sure $of_options[] is the variable/method that is used in the newer version?

Comment: Yes! I see how it is done in the demo and did the same.

Comment: I see this code here https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework/blob/master/admin/functions/functions.options.php#L364-369  but I am still puzzled on the question.  Could you elaborate more please.

Comment: Got the solution. First of all need to click on "Options Reset" button. And after that it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
$options[] = array(
      'name' => __('your name', 'options_framework_theme'),
      'desc' => __('your description', 'options_framework_theme'),
      'id' => 'counter',
      'std' => 'Default Value',
      'type' => 'text'
 );
```